# How to print only Tomcat version

Tags: tomcat

when i am finding the tomcat version, its displaying all the information about the tomcat like this below.

```
./version.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Server built:   Apr 8 2014 08:47:08
Server number:  7.0.28.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.15.4-x86_64-linode45
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_55-b14
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

But instead of that, i just want to print only server version like below

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
```

can you please help me on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your script to `grep`:

```
./version.sh | grep -i "Server version"
```

Comment: Thanks lot for the quick response, its working fine as i am expected, i added above command inside my shell script.